# How to Interpret Audi Tire Pressure Guide

Tags: audi, tire-pressure

I have the following tire pressure guide that I got from the car’s door:
[image]

Not sure how to interpret it.

My tire is 215/65 R 17 99V, looking at the guide, am assuming my tires should be set to 38 PSI, but am not really sure if I’m looking at this correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 38psi.

It does suggest reading the manual, as that will contain additional information when 2, 3 or 5 people with and without luggage etc